# Custom AuthenticationHandler is called when a method has [AllowAnonymous]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to have my own custom authentication for my server. But it is called for every endpoint even if it has the [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the method. With my current code, I can hit my breakpoint in the HandleAuthenticateAsync method everytime, even on the allow anonymous functions.

The AddCustomAuthentication adds the authenticationhandler correctly

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // the scheme name has to match the value we're going to use in AuthenticationBuilder.AddScheme(...)
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "scheme";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "scheme";
            })
            .AddCustomAuthentication(o => { });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }


...

    public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthenticationOptions>
    {

        public RvxAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<RvxAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }


        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var token = Request.Headers["token"].ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Credentials");
            }


            return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(), "Hi"));
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how it is designed to work.

Authentication step is executed for every incoming call by the ASP.Net middleware added by your `app.UseAuthentication()` call. The step only sets up an instance of `IPrincipal` to the request.

If authentication succeeds, the request gets the `IPrincipal` that you pass to the `AuthenticationTicket`.

If it fails, the request gets an unauthenticated `IIdentity` in its `IPrincipal` (`principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will be `false`)

Then the request will still be passed to the next middleware and eventually to your endpoint method.

It's the `AuthorizeAttribute` that will prevent the request from reaching protected methods, not any `AuthenticationHandler<T>`.

Answer (score 20):

Add this to the top of your `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var endpoint = Context.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>() != null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
        }

        ....
    }
```

This is what Microsoft use under the covers in the `AuthorizeFiler` - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bd65275148abc9b07a3b59797a88d485341152bf/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Authorization/AuthorizeFilter.cs#L236

It will allow you to use the `AllowAnonymous` attribute in controllers to bypass your custom `AuthenticationHandler`.

Comment: Did not hit breakpoint, how do you declare this in `Startup.cs` (op method doesnt work on .NET 5)?

Comment: good answer, this is what I exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Your problem is different, After exiting from the
HandleAuthenticateAsync method it can not find the endpoint:

1. because the address is not correct
2. or it goes in error before exiting the HandleAuthenticateAsync method.
   (For example on Request.Headers["Authorization"] as the header "Authorization" does not exists : fires an Exception.).
   Recommendation:
   Use Shlager UI to test the Api first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).